# Are there ORM (OKM) for key-value stores?

Tags: database, orm, nosql

Object-Relational-Mappers have been created to help applications (which think in terms of objects) deal with stored data in a more application-friendly way like every other class/object.

However, I have never seen a OKM (Object-Key/Value-Mapper) for NoSQL "Key/Value" storage systems. Which seems odd because the need should be far greater given the fact that more value-relations will have to be hard-coded into the app than a regular, single SQL table row object.

```
four requests:
user:id
user:id:name
user:id:email
user:id:created

vs one request:
user = [id => ..., name => ..., email => ...]
```

Plus you must keep track of "lists" (post has_many comments) since you don't have has_many through tables or foreign keys.

```
INSERT INTO user_groups (user_id, group_id) VALUES (23, 54)

vs

usergroups:user_id = {54,108,32,..}
groupsuser:group_id = {23,12,645,..}
```

And there are lots more examples of the added logic that an application would need to replicate some basic features that normal relational databases use. All of these reasons make the idea of a OKM sound like a shoe-in.

Are there any? Are there any reasons there are not any?

Comment: ORM for Key-Value?  Um .. what would it do, exactly? Isn't the problem more or less serialization/deserialization of the "Value" or document.

Comment: @qstarin I'm not quite sure yet, though it could handle the relations that your application would otherwise need to track (like lists). There is a lot more that must be handled by your app when you leave the SQL world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby's [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) project is an ORM and will happily talk to a key-value store through the use of an adapter.

[Redis](https://github.com/whoahbot/dm-redis-adapter/) and [MongoDB](https://github.com/solnic/dm-mongo-adapter) have adapters that already exist.  CouchDB has an adapter — it's not maintained, but at one point it worked pretty well.  I don't think anyone's done anything with Cassandra yet, but there's no reason it couldn't be done.  The [Dubious framework](https://github.com/mirah/dubious) for Google App Engine takes a very similar approach to Data Mapper to make the Data Store available to applications.

So it's very possible to do ORM with key-value stores.  The ORM just really needs to avoid the assumption that SQL is its primary vocabulary.

Comment: I was going going to mention CouchModel :P

Comment: Now I just need to decide if I should switch to ruby - or port one of these libraries. The dm-redis-adapter looks like it's on the right track.

Answer (score 4):

One of the design goals of SQL is that any data can be stored/queried in any relational database - There are some differences between platforms, but in general the correct way to handle a particular data structure is well known and easily automated but requiring fairly verbose code. That is not the case with NoSQL - generally you will be directly storing the data as used in your application rather than trying to map it to a relational structure, and without joins or other object/relational differences the mapping code is trivial.

Beyond generating the boilerplate data access code, one of the main purposes of an ORM is abstraction of differences between platforms. In my experience the ability to switch platforms has always been purely theoretical, and this lowest common denominator approach simply won't work for NoSQL as the platform is usually chosen specifically for capabilities not present on other platforms. Your example is only for the most trivial key value store - depending on your platform you most likely have some useful additional commands, so your first example could be

MGET user:id:name user:id:email ... (multiget - get any number of keys in a single call)

GET user:id:* (key wildcards)

HGETALL user:id (redis hash - gets all subkeys of user)

You might also have your user object stored in a serialized form - unlike in a relational database this will not break all your queries.

Working with lists isn't great if your platform doesn't have support built in - native list/set support is one of the reasons I like to use redis - but aside from potentially needing locks it's no worse than getting the list out of sql.

It's also worth noting that you may not need all the relationships you would define in sql - for example if you have a group containing a million users, the ability to get a list of all users in a group is completely useless, so you would never create the groupsuser list at all and rather than a seperate usergroups list have user:id:groups as a multivalue property. If you just need to check for membership you could set up keys as usergroups:userid:groupid and get constant time lookup.

I find it helps to think in terms of indexes rather than relationships - when setting up your data access code decide which fields will need to be queried and adding appropriate index records when those fields are written.

Comment: Very true, The different feature sets of the NoSQL databases as well as the different types (document vs KVP) would certainly mean a custom ORM wrapper for each one to leverage all the strengths and design choices. However, I always think of data as meaningful relations, because that is how it is requested on web pages. Someone comes to see a post - and wants to also see that posts tags and comments or someone goes to a users profile - and also wants to see that users recent activity. So I know there must be some way to write a OKM wrapper (or ODM for document databases) which can relate data.

Comment: Actually the user generally doesn't think about anything resembling what is in the database, so it's what the developer sees that matters. A big part of the value of an orm is being able to access Post.Tags instead of writing a new query. With a database supporting documents or multivalue columns, tags are already part of your document, so it's not needed. With a key value database holding lists in keys you just need to retrieve post:id:tags as part of your initial query, so it's not needed.

Comment: For relating seperate objects like comments, there is no schema or automatic indexing, so orm code cannot be generated from schema and you cannot query by comment.postid unless you set something up manually, in which case you are better off using the native api directly anyway - something like: var a = GET commentindex:postId; MGET a

Comment: @Tom Clarkson Your first example of storing Post tags inside the post object doesn't make sense. The point of tags is to find related objects/posts. However, if the tags for each post are embed in the post object - then the only way you could find all posts tagged with `star-wars` would be fetch each post object and see if it had that tag. Obviously this would work for anything more than 100 posts. As for your second comment - you are describing the failure of trying to map SQL ORM's to NoSQL data which, as you pointed out, won't work. I want to know about mapping a smart OKM object to NoSQL.

Comment: For storage it makes perfect sense - when you display a post you want to display the tags on that post. For finding other posts you have to remember that with most NoSQL systems query/search is quite seperate from storage - if loading all documents isn't good enough you need to set up a tag index. The ORM issues also apply to what you call OKM - you either mean a trivial wrapper class which isn't worth developing as a seperate system or something more like full featured ORM which due to the nature of NoSQL systems is next to impossible to develop for very little benefit.

Comment: 1) That was my point, if you need to setup a tag index - then why would you put the tags in the post object? 2) sounds like you need an answer to this question also. The only thing either of us are doing is making guesses at the functionality and complexity something like a OKM would be. I still want to know if anyone has ever worked on, or thought up something like this.

Comment: 1) Think of it as a multivalue column, with an index to allow efficient querying on that value. 2) I have written code to do this sort of thing myself, and generally it ends up being pretty trivial (though not automatable), usually just a property for key format and updating the right indexes when an item is saved. The reason complex ORM code exists is because relational tables are inconvenient to work with in code and heirarchical objects don't easily fit in a SQL database. With NoSQL systems that difference/mapping requirement usually simply doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

ORMs don't map terribly well to the schema-less nature of key-value stores. That being said, if you're using Riak and Ruby, you could take a look at [Ripple](https://github.com/seancribbs/ripple). There are a number of other drivers for Riak which might fit with your language.

If you're looking into MongoDB (more of a document store than a k/v store), there are a number of [drivers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) available.

Comment: Correct ORM's don't map well to key-value stores - that's why I proposed the new class of "OKM". After all, we have mapped everything from XML to images to sockets to database results using objects in our code - why not map key-value storage? Thanks, I'll take a look at Ripple. I don't use ruby but I might be able to get some ideas from it.

Answer (score 0):

The UNIVERSE db , which is a descendent of Pick, lets you store a list of key value pairs for a given key. However this is very old technoligy and the world ran away from these databases a long time ago.

You can implement this in an SQL database with a three column table

```
  CREATE TABLE ATTRS ( KEYVAL VARCHAR(32),
                       ATTRNAME VARCHAR(32),
                       ATTRVAR  VARCHAR(1024)
                     )
```

Although most DBAs will hit you over the head with the very thick Codd and Date hardback edition if you propose this, it is in fact a very common pattern in packaged applications to allow you to add site specific attributes to a system.

To prarphrase Richrd Stallmans comments on LISP. 
"Any reasonably functional datastorage system will eventually end up implementing there own version of RDBMS."